# Move cursor to the given point value in emacs

Tags: elisp, emacs24

Short story: Given a position value in the buffer say, 12345, how to take the cursor to the position directly
Long story: when i debug my emacs initial boot messages, it prints an error message as,

```
eval-buffer(#...........................) ; Reading at buffer position 19352
```

The fact, no line numbers are printed & only the position value is there makes my navigation tough. any clues, to make my cursor to jump to the position 19352?

Comment: If you are interested in emacs related stack, check out emacs.stackexchange.com

Comment: will do it, Edgar... tx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply

```
(goto-char 19352)
```

See [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Character-Motion.html)

To enter Lisp code interactively, the eval prompt is `M-:`

Answer (score 0):

You want to use that using the command `goto-char`, which by default is bound to `M-g c`.  So you can do

```
M-g c 19352 RET
```

or, if you forget the binding,

```
M-x goto-char RET 19352 RET
```